# Confimap volume with defaultMode no working？

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

yaml file like below

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: fortune-configmap-volume
spec:
  containers:
  - image: luksa/fortune:env
    env:
    - name: INTERVAL
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: fortune-config
          key: sleep-interval
    name: html-generator
    volumeMounts:
    - name: html
      mountPath: /var/htdocs
  - image: nginx:alpine
    name: web-server
    volumeMounts:
    - name: html
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      readOnly: true
    - name: config
      mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
  volumes:
  - name: html
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: fortune-config
      defaultMode: 0777
```

As you can see,I set the configMap volume `defaultMode` 0777, when I try to modify file in container path `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, it told me operation is not allowed, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62099

Secret, configMap, downwardAPI and projected volumes will be mounted as read-only volumes. Applications that attempt to write to these volumes will receive read-only filesystem errors. Previously, applications were allowed to make changes to these volumes, but those changes were reverted at an arbitrary interval by the system. Applications should be re-configured to write derived files to another location.